# Count pending tasks in futures.ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, future, executor

I am looking for a way of counting the number of pending tasks in python 3.2 futures.ThreadPoolExecutor.

Until know, I have two solutions:
1.- Increase the count of pending tasks on submission and add callback to decrease a count when the task is finished
2.- Keep a list of futures and check which are stil pending

Is there anything more direct (i.e. a property or method of executor)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the celerity project is what you need:
http://docs.celeryproject.org